# Connecting Visual Studio to MySql database with ssl certificate

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, ssl-certificate

I will try to explain the problem best as I can.

My goal:
Connecting Visual Studio (Windows Form Application in c#) to MySql database witch uses ssl. I am using MySql Database option in Data source configuration wizard.

What I have:
Code that works on local database.
Two files, client-‘name’.key and client-‘name’.crt witch is a key and certificate for ssl
I also have username, password, port and database to witch I managed to connect from MySql workbench. So I am sure everything works fine and I am just unable to connect from the app itself.

Things I learned so far:
I know that in order to do so I must use data wizard (or connection string builder) but I have to play with advanced settings. Witch I did with no success.
I have entered information such as username, port, password and database but I dont know how to include ssl information witch I guess is essential.

I hope that you understand my issue and that you will be able to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

I tried making a connection on my own but I have never connected to remote server and have no experience doing so.

Comment: Based on the official documentation [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html), you need to generate `PEM` or `PFX`. Also, if you are using `self-signed certificate`, you will get 'verification error'. Could you share `error`?

Comment: @AkifT the error is:
Authentication to host 'host' for user 'user' using method 'caching_sha2_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'user' (using password: YES)

Also I am using certificate that I got from my provider so its not self-signed.
I will look into doc you sent me. Thanks.

Comment: @nnichols
Not really, I am trying stuff from there but I got confused with fields such as: SslCa, SslCert and SslKey. 
I found this about MySqlConnectionStringBuilder, witch I am trying to use:
[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.htm)
There it says for those variables:
'Gets or sets the path to a local file that contains...'. Does that need to be on a specific location or where I decide? Also do I specify the whole path or just the file name?

Comment: @nnichols I run this: `SELECT * FROM performance_schema. session_status WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN ('Ssl_version','Ssl_cipher');`
and got both the cipher and ssl version. So I am sure that the connection from Workbench to server is encrypted.
I put database to Use SSL: Require

Comment: @nnichols
`var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder {
Server = "", UserID = "", Password = "", Database = "", Port = , SslMode = MySqlSslMode.VerifyCA, SslCert = "D:/cert/client-crt.pem", SslKey = "D:/cert/client--key.pem"
};`
Here is the code I tried now and I got error:
SSL Connection error

`MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = builder.ToString();
conn.Open();`

Thats the code I am using to connect to server.

Comment: @nnichols From my issuer I only got those two files (key and cert) and username, host, password, and database. Nothing more.

Comment: I have .crt file within. What do you mean by root cert. I only have one .crt file. 
Sorry if I dont understand, I am new to all this.

Comment: Yes! Both .crt and .key file contain various letters and numbers between delimiters.
Only one big chunk of text between BEGIN and END

Comment: Well, you are the only help I have now. Basically only thing that I am doing now is changing stuff and trying. I will try that as well. 
Do I have to change any particular settings inside Visual Studio in order for ssl to work?

Comment: I really hope so, my guess after all this is that I missed something in requirements. Like some Visual Studio settings or something like that. Since I am trying this for 2 days. 
I will play a bit more with settings and all that and if I manage to make it work I will post the solution. Or maybe someone more experienced will notice the thread.

Comment: @nnichols Yes sir, I did. But without much success.

Comment: Try requesting ca.pem from issuer. Sorry we have not managed to resolve this. Good luck!

Comment: @nnichols Thanks very much. I will see what I can do, I tried now to put SslMode to None and I get Access denied. 
Really thanks for the time and I hope someone with more experience will come.